# Can't resolve dependency in Android Studio with jcenter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

Why my program hang on resolving dependency for appDebug in andorid studio? I can't resolve any library.

This is my root  gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

and this is my app gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alimohammadi.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

And I can't resolve junit. And I can't access to https://jcenter.bintray.com/ with my browser (it gave me connection time out while other site return true response).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After one day time wasting i found that it's gift for Iranian developer :D

Finally i switch back to mavenCentral().by changing to  mavenCentral() in my root gradle . and problem solved.

My root build.gradle file turn to below code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {

   mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

Some library don't exist in mevenCentral so we have to add proxy to our gradle.properties file like below to access jcenter :D

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
```

Or for https

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=user
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
```

Comment: really nice!!!! I was struggling with how to add proxy. we will get heart Attack with these problems soon .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of investigation solution came to me unexpectedly. - Try building your gradle with different network or mobile hotspot. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the exact same issue when I tried to include in my build.gradle the following dependency
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
in order to have

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}
```

I got Timeout on gradle resolution path. So far (when only the classpath to the `gradle:2.3.0` was present), I in fact was working with my cache, so I didn't notice that my proxy was not correctly set.

So I tried to select manual proxy: `Settings->Apperance&Behaviour-> System Settings ->Http Proxy` with Hostname and port number.
So the associated `gradle.properties` was:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy<blabla>.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=123    (123 is just an example)
```

but I still had the problem. Caramba!! So I noticed that the files I needed are located here:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/

but Android studio does not provide a UI to set the proxy on HTTPS so I manually edit the `gradle.properties` to duplicate the line for https

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy<blabla>.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=123    (123 is just an example)
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy<blabla>.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=123
```

And.... it works for me. Don't need to change jcenter to mavenCentral.