# Connection timed out: connect in Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

After installing Android 3.1.3, the final part of the work in Gralde is faced with the following error?

[image: Error in Configure Build Gradle]

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adel.myapplication2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**build.gradl(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I noticed that there is no need for files in jcenter ()
For example, this path does not exist at site !!!
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom'
What should I do?

Comment: Was this working before? What is the URL you are using for the `jcenter()` repository?

Comment: The default settings are Android Studio and I did not change the repository.

Comment: I also created PATH and JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_HOME default paths, but it does not seem to be a problem with these sections!

Comment: Try what this answer to a similar question suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243768/4851565

Comment: I tried, but still it's not possible to fix it !!
The end section does not work on downloading gradle-3.1.2.jar and gradle-3.1.2.pom files !!
Is it possible to separate the files in its path? Where is the path to which these files should be placed?

Comment: please upload your grade script and full stack trace.

Comment: I noticed that there is no need for files in jcenter ()
For example, this path does not exist at site !!!
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom'
What should I do?

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy

Comment: Thank you
The answer worked in the following link :) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy/26840246#26840246)